# Generating a pdf using itext and displaying it on the browser

Tags: jsp, pdf, itext

I had successfully written a code in jsp to generate a pdf file using itext. it works fine but instead of generating the pdf instantly, it generates it partially. It's only when I switch to another tab or window and switch back to the original one, does it display the entire thing correctly.

The solution would be to create a pdf file in the server, open it in the browser window and delete it from server memory as soon as it is opened. Can anyone help me in that?

[Here's a condensed approximation of the program.]

```
    <%@ page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true" %> 
<%@
page import="java.servlet.*,
javax.servlet.http.*,
java.io.*,
java.util.*,
com.lowagie.text.pdf.*,
com.lowagie.text.*"
%>

<%@ include file="connection.jsp" %>
<%
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
Document document = new Document();
try
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, buffer); 
    document.open();
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
    table.addCell("1");
    table.addCell("2");
    table.addCell("3");
    table.addCell("4");
    table.addCell("5");
    table.addCell("6");
        document.add(table);        
    document.close(); 

    DataOutputStream dataOutput = new DataOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
    byte[] bytes = buffer.toByteArray();
    response.setContentLength(bytes.length);
    for(int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++)
        dataOutput.writeByte(bytes[i]);

    dataOutput.flush();
    dataOutput.close();
    return;
}

catch(DocumentException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}

%>
```

Comment: Any reason for using iText in jsp's its considered as the bad convention . rather use a servlet

Comment: i agree with @sankrish...try using a servlet and let us know...

Answer (score 0):

If you copied your actual code, you are creating a PDF that is corrupt from the start. You are introducing white space and newlines, for instance here:

```
%>

<%@ include file="connection.jsp" %>
```

This needs to be changed into:

```
%><%@ include file="connection.jsp" %>
```

As you are introducing bytes into the PDF that don't belong there.

Furthermore, it surprises me that your code actually works, because the moment you introduce white space or a new line, the method `response.getOutputStream()` is implicitly triggered.

I would expect a `java.lang.IllegalStateException` saying "`getOutputStream()` has already been called for this response" when you explicitly get the output stream.

All in all: it's a bad idea to use JSP to create binary files. You should use a servlet. The behavior you're describing is typical for broken PDFs. I think your PDF is broken due to the way you're using JSP.